# Retrieve partly selected text when the cell is in edit mode in DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am trying to retrieve selected text when a Data-grid View cell is in edit mode. I've attached custom Menu strip with Data-grid View.
Attached is the snapshot of what is done till now.

[image: Snap-shot of current progress]

Now, I need to retrieve the highlighted Text i.e. "together form" (in case of attached snapshot) when any of Context Menu Item is clicked.

```
private void tagToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // I want to access highlighted Text here
    }
```

I have exhausted the input parameters : No help from these two parameters.
I have also studied properties of respective Data-grid View but unable to find anything suitable yet.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the editing control from `EditingControl` property if `DataGridView` and check if it's a `TextBox`, get its `SelectedText`:

```
private void tagToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.EditingControl is TextBox)
    {
        var textBox = (TextBox)dataGridView1.EditingControl;
        MessageBox.Show(textBox.SelectedText);
    }
}
```

The editing control of `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn` is [`DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewtextboxeditingcontrol(v=vs.110).aspx) which is derived from `TextBox`.